# What is the difference between map objects and generator objects?

Tags: python, generator, generator-expression

Which of these is best to use in which situations? I'm referring to object made with `map()`, generator expressions, and generator functions.

Here's code I used to view these objects.

```
str_ints = (str(x)for x in range(3))
f = len
map_obj = map(f, str_ints)
gen_obj_from_gen_expression = (f(e) for e in str_ints)

def gen_f():
  for e in str_ints:
    yield f(e)

gen_obj_from_function = gen_f()
for obj in (map_obj, gen_obj_from_gen_expression, gen_obj_from_function):
  print(f'object: {obj}\ntype: {type(obj)}\n')
```

output:

```
object: <map object at 0x7f425c0f3f98>
type: <class 'map'>

object: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f425c1573b8>
type: <class 'generator'>

object: <generator object gen_f at 0x7f425c157570>
type: <class 'generator'>
```

Comment: Both produce iterable values which provide the return value of `f` applied to each element of another iterable, in sequence. There shouldn't be an appreciable different between the two.

Comment: There isn't a big difference. You are basically re-inventing the wheel when it comes to your generators, so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is very little difference between these objects. The reason they are different objects comes from the ability of the `map` function to take multiple iterables.

In that case, it iterates over all of them and on every iteration, invokes the function with elements from every one of them. It stops when the shortest iterable is finished, which is not something a regular generator is capable of doing.

Comment: A generator can use `zip` to the same effect. I don't see much of a need for `map` unless you are passing it as a function to something else, and you only need `yield` when the algorithm gets complicated. (IMHO of course!)

Comment: "They reason they are different objects comes from the ability of the map function to take multiple iterables." no, that isn;t true